# how to pass revision to nginx server

Tags: nginx

My question is related to configuration.
I try use bellow URL for static contents.

`/webpack/rev1/js/vendor.js`

a part of ngnix.conf

```
location  /webpack  {
  location ~ .+/${ ##rev1 --> problem
     alias /var/www/webpackjs
  }
  expires 1000d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I trying to solve my question . I use bellow code at `ngnix.conf`

```
location ~ ^/webpack/rev[^/]+/(.+) {
       try_files  /dist/webpack/$1 /dist/webpack/$1; 
    }
```